# multiple buttons not being able to set off different things

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

To clarify, the button is **NOT** a user interface element. It is an in-game object.

Here's a picture of the issue : It shows my main problem; I pressed the button that's circled, but it activated the one on the right.

[image]

I'm making a game where you have to complete 10 "chambers" of varying difficulty.

I have currently finished the first level and while finishing up I found an annoying bug I cant seem to fix.

If I have two buttons on a map, it seems that no matter which button I press, it will always do whatever the last one put on the map is going to do.

Also, if one button is activated, the other can't be activated.

I'm using the flashpunk engine/library/whatever and AS3.

The button class:

```
package Sprites
{
    import net.flashpunk.Entity;
    import net.flashpunk.graphics.Tilemap;
    import net.flashpunk.masks.Grid;
    import net.flashpunk.*;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Brad
     */
    public class Button extends Entity
    {

        public var _tiles:Tilemap
        private var _grid:Grid

        private var xa:Number
        private var ya:Number

        private var conTiles:Array

        public function Button(xN:Number, yN:Number, tiles:Array)
        {
            xa = xN
            ya = yN
            conTiles = []
            _tiles = new Tilemap(Assets.Switch, 640, 480, 32, 32)
            graphic = _tiles;
            layer = 1
            conTiles = tiles
            _tiles.setTile(xN, yN, 0)
            _grid = new Grid(640, 480, 32, 32, 0, 0)
            mask = _grid
            _grid.setTile(xN, yN, true)
            name = "Button"
            type = "button"
        }

        public function Activate():void
        {
            var Activated:Boolean = false
            if (!Activated)
            {
                for (var i:Number = 0; i < conTiles.length; i++)
                {
                    trace("Hi!")
                    FP.world["map"]["_tiles"].setTile(conTiles[i].x, conTiles[i].y, 3)
                    FP.world["map"]["_grid"].setTile(conTiles[i].x, conTiles[i].y, false)
                }
                _tiles.setTile(xa, ya, 1)
                Activated = true
            }
            else
                trace("Activated already!")
        }

    }

}
```

How I put the buttons into the world:

```
    public class World1 extends World
    {
        public var startPos:Object = {"x": 45, "y": 135}
        public var player:Player = new Player(startPos["x"], startPos["y"])
        public var button:Button = new Button(5, 6, [new Point(10, 10), new Point(10, 11)])
        public var button2:Button = new Button(7, 6, [new Point(10, 10), new Point(10, 11)])
        public var map:Map1 = new Map1()
        public var finish:Finish = new Finish(14,2,"map1")
        public function World1()
        {
            add(map)
            add(finish)
            add(button)
            add(button2)
            add(player)
            player.layer = 0

            for (var i2:Number = 0; i2 < 9; i2++)
                add(new Wall3D(i2+1, 1))
            for (var i3:Number = 0; i3 < 11; i3++)
                add(new Wall3D(i3, 13))         
            trace("Hi!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move `var Activated:Boolean = false` to class definition, at first. Could do, in fact. Also, use more than "Hi!" in your traces, so you could know *which* trace was that.

Comment: @Vesper, I was thinking to suggest that. Make it a `public var` etc but I can't even see how they call the `Activate` function. This would be so much easier if they just used normal AS3 (a simple `currentTarget` check for `active = true` on clicked item/button, assuming Activate was a MouseEvent function).

Comment: Acivate is called from the player when they're colliding with the button and press E (or X). It isn't a hud or anything.

Comment: [This is the main problem](http://imgur.com/rc4QTSM). I pressed the button circled but it activated the one on the right.

Comment: Seems like your system thinks that any button refers to the last added one. If buttons are accessed by `name` somewhere it may happen because every button has `name = "Button"`. Also as mentioned above - move `var Activated` outside the `function` because like this it cannot really save the button state